# How to make Django present generated mp4

Tags: python, django

I have a docker volume that contains generated mp4 files. I want to find a way to display them in dev because my current solution results in an error.

**error**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/fergana_api/files/36/movies/movie.mp4
Using the URLconf defined in fergana_api.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
api/schema/ [name='api-schema']
api/docs/ [name='api-docs']
api/
[name='all-runs']
tests/<slug:test_session_id> [name='single-run']
tests/<slug:test_session_id>/<slug:test_name> [name='single-test']
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^files/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, fergana_api/files/36/movies/movie.mp4, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = 'files/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/web/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static_files'

# location of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]
```

**app/views.py**

```
class SingleTestView(View):
    def get(self, request, test_session_id, test_name):
        run = Runner.objects.get(id=test_session_id)
        path_to_session = to_file('files/', f'{test_session_id}')
        movies_dir_path = to_file(path_to_session, 'movies')
        movie_path = to_file(movies_dir_path, test_name.replace('-', '_') + '.mp4')
        
        context = {
            'movie_path': movie_path
        }

        return render(request, "presenter/single_test.html", context)
```

**project/url.py**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT
                          )

    urlpatterns += static(
        settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    )
```

**single_test.html**

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="{{ movie_path }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

It seems like the app uses the correct URL to serve files, but it doesn't seem like it can find/access the MEDIA_ROOT

http://127.0.0.1:8000/fergana_api/files/36/movies/movie.mp4

How do I actually make it serve the file located at `/var/web/media/36/movies/movie.mp4` given that the file 100% exists?

1. Please, tell me if you need any more info
2. app is included into the INSTALLED_APPS

**docker-compose**

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: fergana-api.dockerfile
      args:
        - DEV=true
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
      - ./fergana_api:/fergana_api 
      - static-data:/vol/web

volumes:
  static-data:
```

Answer (score 0):

There is couple elements in your example that need to be checking.

You should check your `MEDIA_URL`

Note that `MEDIA_URL` should start with a forward slash /.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/files/'
```

i am guesing your working directory is `/fergana_api` is ( inside your container ).

i am assue you have file in the following path and file already exist
`/fergana_api/files/36/movies/movie.mp4`

i assume you want a file accesible from the following url

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/files/36/movies/movie.mp4`

so you need to tell django to save the media files on `fergana_api/files`

you can do this by setting

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'files')
MEDIA_URL = '/files/'
```

your `app/views.py` file

```
class SingleTestView(View):
    def get(self, request, test_session_id, test_name):
        run = Runner.objects.get(id=test_session_id)
        path_to_session = to_file( f'{test_session_id}')
        movies_dir_path = to_file(path_to_session, 'movies')
        movie_path = to_file(movies_dir_path, test_name.replace('-', '_') + '.mp4')
        
        context = {
            'movie_path': movie_path
        }

        return render(request, "presenter/single_test.html", context)
```

You should try this template

```
{% if movie_path %}
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ movie_path }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
{% else %}
    <p>No video available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

`django.template.context_processors.media` should be added in `TEMPLATES` –>`context_processors`. unless {{ MEDIA_URL }} wont work

You need to add in the settings.py file:

```
context_processors = [
    ...
    'django.template.context_processors.media', 
]
```

I hope it will help